# How to get current working directory from Android Linux kernel?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, android-source

I have a custom Android 7.1 build and trying to add a wifi driver to it.

The Realtek driver loads the correct rtl8xxxu.ko module file but it is giving a file not found error when it tries to load the BIN image for the USB module. The files are present in what should be the correct location in a directory called rltwifi in the same directory as the rtl8xxxu.ko module file. I've even tried putting them in the lib/firmware/rtlwifi directory with no success.

As a debug option, I am trying to find out how to add temporary code to the kernel to print to the debug output from the **firmware_class.c** file just prior to the file attempting to be opened.

I've tried to use getcwd() but if I #incude  it fails with unistd.h not being found. Adding #include  gives no missing file but the call to getcwd() is not defined.

I've also tried to use sys_getcwd() but this gives me **SUBSYSTEM=usd** as the returned path string.

What do I need to add to the kernel to be able to see what directory the module is run from?